# How to make Angular 4+ apps compatible with Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, compatibility

I'm currently developing [a component for Angular 2+](https://github.com/johannesjo/angular2-promise-buttons) and I'm using `Render2` over `Renderer` and `InjectionToken` over `OpaqueToken` as the latter are considered deprecated. This however leads to the component not being compatible with Angular2. Is there a smart way to conditionally swap out the dependencies, depending on which Version of angular is used? E.g. something like:

```
import {Renderer, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

// use deprecated Renderer for angular2.x when Renderer2 is not available
let RendererToUse;
if (typeof Renderer2 === 'function') {
  RendererToUse = Renderer2;
} else {
  RendererToUse = Renderer;
}

export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private renderer: RendererToUse) {
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use OpaqueToken in A4 as well. The whole purpose of having Renderer2 is that it has different API. You can't just swap one with another. You can conditionally retrieve it with injector.get, but a cleaner solution may be to have 2 different branches. And the use of Renderer may not be justified at all.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about this too. However I still would be interested in a solution that deals with that in a singular branch, because maintaining different branches and publishing different versions from there, would get messy quickly.

Comment: The solution is `injector.get(Renderer2, null) || injector.get(Renderer)`. But you will end up with objects that have different API. I would suggest to use OpaqueToken and Renderer as common denominators and don't look any further. Renderer is currently used by A4 directives.